# How to create a Dynamic Dropdown List?

Tags: excel

I have a list with full of names (Andy, Peter, etc.). There is no duplicates between the names. They start at C1 to C10. From A1 to A10 I want to make a Dropdown with the names, but I want to use every name only once. So if Peter is choosed in A1, then he can not be on the list in A2. How can I make it?

Thanks a lot.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions on the following website and let us know if it helps! http://trumpexcel.com/2014/07/multiple-drop-down-lists-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from the second drop down using onselect javascript event.